# Getting information from a web service response

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get to the information from a web service response.
I know that response is an object, that it has several different fields (`name`, `id`, etc.), that one of the fields, called `settings`, can be one of the three types (depending on the response) `typeA`,`typeB` and `typeC`, and that all of these types are objects and have their own fields.

I can get to `name` and `id` using `response.name` or `response.id`.
If I use `response.settings`, I get one of the answers: `typeA`, `typeB`, and `typeC`.  I know that `typeA` has field `size` and I want to get to it, how can I do that?  Even if I know that the respons's `settings` is `typeA`,  I still can't use `response.settings.typeA.size`; I get an error.
How can I write that if `response`'s `settings` is `typeA`, I can get to `typeA.size`?

Comment: You would have to show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question, You have a response object and You don't know the type of `settings`, it can be typeA, typeB or typeC.
You can check its type with the `is` operator.

```
if(response.settings is typeA)
...
```

Here you can find a [SAMPLE](http://ideone.com/vVGjrP). The only difference: in this code typeA stands alone, not part of a bigger object.

Comment: i understand how i can get type, but what i do next?
okay,i know it is `typeA`, but i can't do `response.settings.typeA.size`, how can i get to typeA's size?

Comment: typeA is not a field, You should remove it from there.

Comment: so how can i get to `size`?
response.settings[some kind of checking if it is typeA].size??
i have no idea what to do

Comment: nope, first You check its type and when You know it is typeA, then You can get it with 'response.settings.size'

Comment: if i try something like 
if(response.settings.GetType() is typeA){
int size=response.settings.size;
}
i doesn't work

Comment: it says that setting doesn't contain definition for size.
and when i write response.settings. i get list of things i can choose and there is no field called `size`

Comment: i got it! but it is written very strange (for me):
((typeA)(response.settings)).size
when i was trying to check my value with break point, visual showed me this kind of way

thank you very much for help!

Comment: @Alma don't forget to check the type before You try to cast it. And because You're a new member I tell You: if You are satisfied with an answer, You should accept or upvote it(or of course You can wait for better explanations).